# getSize always return zero

Tags: android

I am trying to capture the area of the finger touching the screen and also the amount of pressure over the screen. I have tried `Motionevent.getsize()` and I always get a value of 0. Also, `Motionevent.getpressure()` always gives me a value of 1.

Other functions like getX(), getY(), and getEventTime() seem to work fine.  Is there another way to get the size and pressure of the touch event?

Comment: Does your device support those measurements?

Comment: Have you tried to run Pointer Location from Dev Tools?

Comment: Just wondering are you passing in the `pointerIndex` as a parameter? According to the developer API, the [getPressure()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getPressure%28int%29) method requires that.

Answer (score 0):

Returns a scaled value of the approximate size for the given pointer index (use `MotionEvent.GetPointerId(int)` to find the pointer identifier for this index). This represents some approximation of the area of the screen being pressed; the actual value in pixels corresponding to the touch is normalized with the device specific range of values and scaled to a value between 0 and 1. The value of size can be used to determine fat touch events.

Answer (score 0):

For getPressure()

Returns the current pressure of this event for the given pointer index (use getPointerId(int) to find the pointer identifier for this index). The pressure generally ranges from 0 (no pressure at all) to 1 (normal pressure), however values higher than 1 may be generated depending on the calibration of the input device.

this information is right out of the Android documentation...here is a helpful link with many other functions you might find useful:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getPressure%28int%29